# Generate a 2 random color on the same text

Tags: flutter

I'm new in a flutter. I can't figure out how to generate the 2 random colours on the same Text(). Can anyone help me out? Really appreciate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
String data = "+RM67.80";
var value = data.substring(0,1); // it will get the first character
```

After that you can check the condition if **value == "+"** apply green color otherwise apply red.